# Get time to populate a POSTGRES table from csv file

Tags: postgresql, csv, rdbms, bulk-load

Is there any way to determine the time which the Postgres takes to populate a table from a csv file. I tried using 'time' command but it did not work.

```
time copy TABLE_NAME from /home/ankit/Documents/file.csv delimiter ',' csv header ;
```

The error was:
`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "time`"

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on how you're submitting the query to Postgres.  If you're using the psql command line client in a shell you can add the time command before it.  So for example it would be something like the following:

```
time psql -c "copy TABLE_NAME from /home/ankit/Documents/file.csv delimiter ',' csv header ;"
```

You might also need to add connection parameters to the command.

Another way if you're using psql is to use the following command and psql will print how much time each query takes:

```
\timing
```

Comment: Yeah! Seems like this is what I wanted. However I need to pass the role and database name too as postgres is not able to locate TABLE_NAME. Any idea how could that be done?

Comment: psql -d <db name> -h <hostname> -p <port> -U <username> -c <command>

Comment: You could also add -W if you want it to prompt for a password

Answer (score 2):

There should be field like "created" of type "timestamp without time zone" in your table and you can also assign default value as now() in the column definition screen.

Then each record will be asseigned with created timestamp either it was loaded from csv or created by any other way.

Or in SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN created TIMESTAMP;
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN created SET DEFAULT now();
```

Comment: Yeah! That could be done. But what I was looking for was some command like 'time'. Thank you for the answer though.